# Web.config in Views subfolder ignored on developer machine, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a root web.config and a secondary Views/web.config added automatically by Visual Studio years ago when the application was created.

Now I have bumped ASP.NET MVC to a newer version (5.2.7), fixed various issues on my developer machine - and everything works for me.

Unfortunately, when pushed to our integration test server, everything fails as there are MVC version references, in the Views/web.config file, that are now invalid for the new MVC version.

I can fix the version issues and everything is 200 OK ... but, and here is my question, why doesn't the errors show up on my local developer machine?

It turns out I can introduce XML syntax errors and what not on my local machine - and nothing happens, everything is okay locally, as if the Views/web.config file is completely ignored by the webserver.

Both machines are running IIS on Windows with the same configuration ... well, except that something apparently is different.

Where should I look to figure out why the Views/web.config is ignored on my developer machine?

The Views/web.config looks like this (with the wrong version numbers included):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="CBrain.F2.SelfService.Mvc.Html" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that IIS behaves a bit strange: once the webpage loads correctly first time, I can change the Views/web.config without IIS detecting the change. But then I modify the main web.config ... whereafter IIS detects my changes in Views/web.config. Guess I have to live with that.